# LibreOffice Calc changes letters from uppercase to lowercase when entering formula

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to enter the following into a cell in LibreOffice Calc:

```
=SUM(Business_Profit,'Sch. C (2)'!Business_Profit)
```

When I do that, as soon as I hit return the input line displays:

```
=SUM(Business_Profit,'sch. c (2)'!Business_Profit)
```

and the cell reference fails (the cell I'm entering into shows:

```
#NAME?
```

I've looked carefully at the Autocorrect options:  every entry in the "Options" tab is unchecked.

Is there a way to get LibreOffice Calc to accept the formula I type into a cell?

I'm not enough of an expert to know for sure that the capitalization change is what's messing up the cell reference.  I do know that I don't have this problem in Excel;  in Excel the formula gets entered the way I type it and the cell reference works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. LibreOffice *Calc* does not like space ('blanks') in labels.
2. Use the [*DefineNames dialog* to label cells or ranges of cells.](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Naming_Cells)
3. When referencing cell names, *Calc* will show the corresponding name as you type. In the example below, cell E1 was named *Grosse_Prophet* and F1, *Nut_Prophet*. As I began typing the formula

> =Grosse_Prophet - nut

*Calc* suggested *Nut_Prophet*. (Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept that name). Notice that the search for the name in *not* case-sensitive.

[image: Nming Calc Cells]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm working with a protected spreadsheet, so I can't change the cell names.  I've tried changing the name of the sheet I'm trying to reference, including g going to all lower case, with no success.  There may be something different about the way LOC and Excel handle cross-sheet references.  In any case, I just discovered that when I tried to print the whole thing in LOC the formatting was all messed up--one two-page sheet turned into 8 pages.  So I'm going have to go back to Excel.

Comment: If it's a protected spreadsheet, then how can you "**enter** the following into a cell in LibreOffice Calc?" And if it's *not* protected, e.g. you made a copy of it in Calc and saved it without protection, then you should be able to change the names of cells.

Answer (score 1):

Two things lead to the forced conversion to lower case:

(1) When entering a formula, Calc changes any unrecognized references to lower case. This happens for both sheet and variable-name references. Check the list in `Insert > Names > Manage` if Calc unexpectedly fails to recognize a variable name.

(2) By default, Calc uses `.` for the sheet scope operator instead of Excel's `!` scope operator. Using

`'Sch. C (2)'.Business_Profit` instead of

`'Sch. C (2)'!Business_Profit`

should make Calc recognize the sheet name and prevent the conversion to lower case.

Another solution is to go to `Tools > Options > LibreOffice Calc > Formula` and change the Formula syntax from `Calc A1` to `Excel A1`. This only appears to affect the display and input-processing of formulas. It does not break existing sheet references. Based on experimentation, Calc also prepends a `$` to the sheet name if an inter-sheet reference was initially created in `Excel A1` mode.